# What do we need to authorise the Google app scripts? (Because scripts are even working with authorisation)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I had created a spreadsheet which alerts me whenever a stock price moves beyond a limit.

For alerts, I had integrated Pushbullet in the spreadsheet through the app script. But whenever I create a copy of that spreadsheet, I do not need to authorize the script to keep receiving alerts.

Though, I need to authorize the script if I run it from the Google App script inbuilt tool.

One more thing I discovered is that you need to compulsorily authorize the script if the triggers are manual but in my case the triggers are automated based on the price fluctuations so I don't need to authorize the code to keep running the scripts.

I also had a spreadsheet where I send emails by clicking a button and there I need to authorize the script.

Question: If the script is not authorized then why I'm still receiving alerts?
And what is the real reason behind authorizing the Google scripts?

Following is the link to the spreadsheet. You can also find the code for Pushbullet in the app script which is not authorized. And I'm still receiving the push notifications.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HhvLDU_rTbYzDX7wY9TnZIarShxQJMJK8AHlUoEon7A

Create a copy and add your email associated with pushbullet to receive notifications on your device. Don't forget to change the boolean value to "Yes".

Comment: Please confirm that your script is a bounded script and not an stand-alone script. By the other hand I don't think that the integration of Pushbullet is relevant, if so, please describe how do you did the integration and include a [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén I had added a link to the demo spreadsheet. Enter your email address and try changing the boolean value from to "Yes". You'll receive push notifications. Also, check whether the script is authorized after you start receiving the notifications. And it's not.

Comment: Including a link to a demo spreadsheet is fantastic (actually I think that it should be required). I think that very few people will follow the link and spend time trying to understand it's structure, in other words, the demos should include the minimal sheets/columns/rows and the relevant formulas and code should be included in the question itself. That way the question will have more chances to get answers from consolidated experts, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind authorization or  reauthorizing of the Google app script is that, the script can be shared with multiple users and script has ability to access almost all Google apps data (e.g Gmail, Spreadsheet, Doc, Drive, Map etc.), which is / may be confidential information of that owner.

Therefore Owner must compile / run script first time and whenever there will be any service change then Owner must have to authenticate again.

Thanks.

Comment: But still, the script runs even if it's not authorized. Question is, if it's not authorized then how it access the email address associated with pushbullet and send them notifications.

Comment: @SowmayJain The script is always authorized to owner because you have login with Google and authorized it by default.

Comment: @SowmayJain If you still have a  questions you can read Google's authorization conditions and policies..best luck.